# Python unittest debugging in vscode

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code, python-unittest

I would like to attach a debugger while running the unittest module. I can't seem to find any info about this via the google. Does anyone have a config that would allow debugging into the python test runner? The other this is that i use the discover arg to match my test pattern. I don't mind having to debug individual files but it would be nice to just fire the debugger with a config i don't need to monkey with whenever i need to change to a different file.

`python -m unittest discover -p "*_test.py"`

I've tried adding this config

```
    {
      "name": "Python: Unittest",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "module": "unittest",
      "args": ["discover", "-p", "'*_test.py'"]
    },
```

but i get `no matches found: '*_test.py'` error...

anyone got ideas? another way to debug into the unittest runner?

Comment: have you told which directory to look for test files, does the `Debug Test` Codelens not work

Comment: Yeah, tried even having a single test at the root for simplicity. I've tried a bunch of different ways... i'm not sure what `Debug Test` codelens means?

Comment: If the test discovery works you see a Codelens line above the test, see python doc about testing, test discovery is specified with setting `python.testing.unittestArgs` NOT in the launch.json

Answer (score 5):

1.Press **Ctrl+Shift+P** to open Command Platte;

2.Select **Python: Discover Tests**, there'll be a notification to let you Enable and configure a Test Framework:

[image]

3.Choose Unittest, then you can choose the option to identify test files:
[image]

Above all is written in **workspace settings.json**:
[image]

So you can set the identification rule by the setting:

```
"python.testing.unittestArgs":[]
```

About Debug all tests, the **Python: Debug All Tests** and **Python: Debug Test Method** commands (on both the Command Palette and Status Bar menu) launch the debugger for all tests and a single test method, respectively.

More detailed information, please refer to [Testing](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/testing) and [Debug Tests](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/testing#_debug-tests).

Comment: Currently log.debug statements are going to the Debug console, not Terminal..how do we change that to print out in the Terminal console - is there a setting in this config for that?